# How to run on ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7

I have to run this file `reddit-job-update_popular_subreddits.conf`.
I go to the file directory using `cd` command and I put this `./reddit-job-update_popular_subreddits.conf`but its not work. "Comand not found"

Can someone help me with a line ?
Thanks

Comment: `conf` is not supposed to be executable file. Why are you trying to run it and where did you find to do so? Could you please paste a source?

Comment: Here: https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/4jhyiq/reddit_under_rrandom/

Answer (score 2):

`.conf` files are configuration files and they are usually not supposed to be run as binary files nor anyone says that you should do that in the link you provided.
Taking a look at the code of the program you are running, my best bet would be to run the program as usual but with the `conf` file as an argument.

For example:
`python subreddit.py reddit-job-update_popular_subreddits.conf`